# Increasing width of text box inside Icon.ToolbarAndroid

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-toolbar

I'm trying to create a search box inside Icon.ToolbarAndroid component. But I can't change the width of the text box to take up all the area till the message icon. Can someone help me here?

[image]

Following is the code I've used. (I've also tried putting minWidth also.)

```
            <Icon.ToolbarAndroid
            actions={[
                { title: 'Chat', iconName: 'chat', iconSize: 24, show: 'always' },
                { title: 'Alert', iconName: 'notifications', iconSize: 24, show: 'always' }
            ]}
            navIconName="menu"
            title=""
            style={styles.toolbar}
            onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}
            onIconClicked={this.onIconClicked.bind(this)}
        >
            <TextInput style={styles.searchBox}  minWidth={40}>Testing</TextInput>
        </Icon.ToolbarAndroid>
```

Here's the styling I used.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    toolbar: {
        backgroundColor: '#2D4571',
        height: 48,
    },
    searchBox: {
        backgroundColor: '#4D648D',
        color: '#eeeeee',
        width: 40
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the results by wrapping the text input in a view. But it only works when a backgroundColor is given. If I remove the color it sizes back to the above picture.

```
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffaabb', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <TextInput style={styles.searchBox} >Testing </TextInput>
            </View>
```